# sendgrid_webapi event notification sendgrid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sendgrid

I'm having difficulty retrieving the event notifications for my SendGrid account and I'm not sure how to proceed.

I'm utilizing the sendgrid_webapi gem (https://github.com/kylejginavan/sendgrid_webapi) and I'm attempting to retrieve the event notifications for the client using the barebones implementation that the README.rdoc provides.

Very simple:

```
client = SendGridWebApi::Client.new(*user*, *password*)
notifications = client.event_notification.get()
return notifications
```

Each of the other calls (bounces, unsubscribes, etc.) work as expected, but for some reason I've been unable to retrieve anything other than the URL that I've specified within the SendGrid interface (I've enabled all events and the event notification app).

The documentation for the gem states that the options available can be found at http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/event.html but I've been unable to take that information and turn it into something tangible that I can use when making the call.

I feel like this is just something simple that I'm missing, but any help / guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: webhooks are setup such that you give a url to SendGrid and SendGrid will do a HTTP POST to that url in real time when an event happens.  Also you need to be on the Silver package or above to enable webhooks

Answer (score 1):

The API call you are trying to use is for configuring the Event Webhook, not for consuming events.

A webhook is a "push" API rather than one that you query for information. You need to setup a URL with a script that can handle HTTP posts from SendGrid in order to use the webhook.

Here is a gem called [gridhook](https://github.com/leejarvis/gridhook) that can do what you need.